# Sum and average of values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to ask how to add the values and find average of values in an array. I have tried searching multiple times, but I could find something that explains how to do all that in simple code that a new programmer such as myself could understand. If someone could tell me how to do it and explain the codes used, that will be great. Thanks in advance :>

Comment: Make an attempt to write a code that does it, and post it here for help. I would suggest to start with creating an array and then looping over it.

Comment: @c0der Alright. Will try to do so:>

Comment: @c0der Just hover over the "down" button and you see what it means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." The first part clearly applies here. Asking for "the codez" without showing any research effort is not something people like on SO.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Ofcourse I did my research. I searched multiple times(in google and in SO. I couldn't find what I was looking for. :<

Comment: @MohanRam The keyword here is *show*. In this particular case: to "research" a programming problem, you try to write the program and then you can show that research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to take an array of numbers. Iterate all the numbers in the array and add the numbers to a variable. Thus after iteration you will get the sum of the numbers. Now divide the sum by count of numbers (which means the size of array). Thus you will get the average.

```
int[] numbers = {10, 20, 15, 56, 22};
double average;
int sum = 0;

for (int number : numbers) {
    sum += number;
}

average = sum / (1.0 * numbers.length);
System.out.println("Average = " + average);
```

You can also iterate in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong, the average is 24.6 not 24.0 in your example.
When dividing two `int` you are omitting the rest of the division.
You can fix this by declaring the `sum` as `double`.

Answer (score 2):

I leave the normal answers for others to do. For java people,Here we go!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myarr[]={1,2,3,4,4,5,6,5,7,8,4};
    IntSummaryStatistics statisticalData=Arrays.stream(myarr).summaryStatistics();
    System.out.println("Average is " + statisticalData.getAverage());
    System.out.println("Sum is " + statisticalData.getSum());
}
```

Other data like count,minimum element,maximum element can also be obtained from the IntSummaryStatistics object

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); //Define Scanner class object which will aid in taking user input from standard input stream.
    int a[] = new int[10]; //Define an array
    int i,sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = s.nextInt(); //Take the arrays elements as input from the user
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //Iterate over the array using for loop. Array starts at index 0 and goes till index array_size - 1
        sum = sum + a[i]; //add the current value in variable sum with the element at ith position in array. Store the result in sum itself.
    }
    double avg = (double) sum / 10; //Compute the average using the formula for average and store the result in a variable of type double (to retain numbers after decimal point). The RHS of the result is type casted to double to avoid precision errors
    System.out.print(sum + " " + avg); //print the result
}
```

Comment: Ohh crap! I forgot to take input! :-P Thanks for pointing it out @c0der! Made the edits!

Answer (score 0):

```
void sumAndAverage(int a[]){
    if(a!=null&&a.length>0{
    int sum=0;
    //traverse array and add it to sum variable
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }
    double avg=(1.0*sum)/a.length;
    System.out.println("sum= "+sum);
    System.out.println("average= "+avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add a check if a is not null nor empty